# Italian language not showed in rendering Latex script

Tags: languages

I am using Texmaker, and I am having a problem about the use of language packages. I have tried to use the Italian Babel, writing the following:

```
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
```

and then either

```
\selectlanguage{Italian} 
text
```

or

```
\begin{otherlanguage*}{italian} 
text
\end{otherlanguage*}
```

but neither work, and my text is not showing the symbols proper of Italian language like a,è,ì,ò,ù.
Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you are typing them directly (`á` instead of `\'a`) you need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (assuming your editor is `utf8` encoded). Or a very recent LaTeX kernel.

Comment: Did you write in your preamble `\usepackage[utf8]{\inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: Off-topic: Note that TeXmaker is just a front-end to a TeX distribution. It doesn't do any typesetting chores. Those are handled by the "back-end", most importantly, something like pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Ooooh, you see. I got it completely wrong. You solved everything, thank you. Just to know, then - what's the languagepackage for?

Comment: Hyphenation and other culture-specific things. Welcome to TeX SX, by the way!